# Most efficient way to remove duplicate elements from a list

Tags: c, data-structures

I have an unsorted list, from which I want to remove duplicates. What is the most efficient to perform this in C. In my case, the list is a linked list of arrays. In other words several arrays linked together. Duplicates can only happen in different arrays. So for example there can't be a duplicate inside array 1, but the same number can be found in array 1 and 2.

Comment: What kind of list? A linked list? Or do you mean an array? What are the data items like? How do you determine equality?

Comment: is the array set? if not dont insert the duplicate into it

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a modification on the [Element Distinctness Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). The link goes through several possible solutions.

One common and simple solution is to just sort the list and make a pass through the sorted list, removing any duplicates. This will get you an O(n*log(n)) algorithm

You can do better (O(n)) if you use a hashtable. Go through the array, inserting each element into a hash table. If you get a collision,  you may have have found a duplicate, and you can do a quick compare against those two elements.

Comment: A collision in a hash table doesn't mean a duplicate, just a 'candidate' to duplicate.

Comment: collision in hash table is more of a chance to NOT be a duplicate, of course it depends on the hashing function, but all of them have avalanche effect

Comment: It's worth mentioning that "better" depends on both the prefactor (which can be quite large for hash functions) and the asymptotic factor.  `log N` grows very slowly, so sorting, with its small prefactor, is often faster for small sets of data.  Also, don't overlook the [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) for numbers (or anything that can be represented by or cast to a number), which is also O(N).